# Knockout JS: property specific css binding expression

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

See the following jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7gS6N/.

I'm trying to perform some simple field-level validation through knockout js.

Click "Add Error" to simulate adding an Error for the Name field.

When an error is added to the Errors collection, the css bindings fire, the expression evaluates to true and the css class is applied.

This is great, but how can I make my css binding expression property specific?

```
css: { error: Errors().length > 0 }
```

I only want the Name field to show the css class.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using Knockoutjs validation plugin? It does what you are looking for https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra observable, so instead of

```
self.Name = ko.observable("John")
```

you use

```
self.Name = new Field("John Smith");
```

where a Field has the following structure

```
function Field(value) {
  var self = this;
  self.value = ko.observable(value);
  self.hasError = ko.observable(false);
}
```

And your markup looks like

```
<div data-bind="with:Name">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: value, css: { error: hasError }" />
</div>
```

This strategy is known as **decorating** an object; in this case I "wrapped" your variables in a class, but from there you can add `label`, `errorMessage` and other attributes you would want all those specific Fields to have. Finally, I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjperezaguinaga/7gS6N/1/) with the working example.